# What is the Soulknife's Mind Blade ability modifier?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I cannot find it anywhere in the official books.

Online, I can find the usual STR modifiers for melee attacks and DEX modifiers for ranged attacked, but I can also find INT modifiers for all psionic abilities--including the Mind Blade, whether it is thrown or not.

What is it, really, and where can I find this information next time?

Comment: Welcome to this stack! Take the [tour]. Can this question be edited to include links to characters that demonstrate a soulknife with Int modifiers added and another without? Thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soulknives don’t have any special rules for ability modifiers. You’ll no more find information on what ability scores a soulknife uses than you will find information on the ability scores a rogue uses: it’s just whatever ability scores are used by default for whatever it is you’re trying to do. Nothing in the class uses ability scores in any special way.

So your melee attacks are made with Strength just like any other melee attack, unless you have Weapon Finesse and use Dexterity. Your melee damage rolls with a mind blade get Strength as a bonus as usual, unless you have Shadow Blade and use Dexterity. (Obviously the mind blade must be in a form compatible with those feats—though the default short sword form works with both.) When you throw the mind blade, you use Dexterity for attacks and Strength to damage, as normal for throwing weapons, unless you have Brutal Throw and use Strength for both. And so on. You *could* use Wisdom (if you have Intuitive Attack or Zen Archery), but it’s not the default.

Whoever said you use Intelligence for all psionic abilities is completely wrong. **Psions** use Intelligence, and they are kind of “the” iconic psionic manifester, but really no one else does. (The lurk might, maybe? The lurk isn’t worth looking up though.) Ardents, psychic warriors, and war minds use Wisdom, and wilders use Charisma.